# Custom Scrollbar: No mouse scroll in non-webkit browsers. (jScrollPane)

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, scrollbar, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

I'm using [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) to create a custom scroll bar style.

View my current code here: http://cwhitaker.com/deck/deck.html

The jScrollPane works in all modern browsers, but the ability to scroll only works in Webkit browsers (Safari & Chrome). Although in the [jScrollPane demos](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/basic.html) the mouse scroll is fully functional in all browsers.

Maybe it has something to do with my columns using absolute position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, the scroll bars were not working with mouse scroll on any browser on the referred webpage.

I copied the entire HTML, CSS and JavaScript code from the webpage referred to in the question to http://jsfiddle.net/ytQMs/.  After making the following changes I was able to get mouse scroll working on all browsers:

1. Link to the latest mouseWheel distribution http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/script/jquery.mousewheel.js
2. Link to the latest jScrollPane distribution http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/script/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js
3. Removed the jQuery corner plugin and its associated line $('.deck-column-title').corner("5px top");

I suggest making these changes in your code and trying out.

Answer (score 0):

You mean scroll using mouseweel? Because I can scroll in firefox using drag&drop. I think you need another plugin to enable mousewheel support in all browsers.

> If the mouse wheel plugin is included in the page then the scroll
>   panes will respond to mouse wheel events as well

http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/mousewheel

Comment: Yeah. I do have mousewheel installed. =/ http://cwhitaker.com/deck/js/jquery.mousewheel.js